# How to use stepic.encode()

Tags: python, python-3.x, steganography, stepic

```
from PIL import Image
import stepic
img = Image.open ('a.png')
img2 = stepic.encode(img, 'hello world')
img2.show()
```

Here the code is giving the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Python 3.6 is used.

Comment: What's the complete traceback error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had the same problem.. I tested on Python 3.6.6 
simply change the line below
FROM:

```
img2 = stepic.encode(img, 'hello world')
```

TO:

```
img2 = stepic.encode(img, b'hello world')
```

you need to pass your data/text as binary